# Looking for way to change gradle init original directory structure to EXCLUDE project name

Tags: gradle, init, directory-structure

I've seen ways to change comments, but looking for a way to change the directory structure of my gradle init command.

For example 1:

```
mkdir newProjectName
cd newProjectName

gradle init --type groovy-application

this creates directory structure: 
src/main/groovy/newProjectName/App.groovy
src/test/groovy/newProjectName/...
```

Ex 2:

```
mkdir new-project-name
cd new-project-name
gradle init --type java-application

this creates directory structure:
src/main/java/new/project/name/App.java
src/test/java/new/project/name/...
```

I'd rather it just create src/main/groovy/App.groovy EXCLUDING the project name. And I like naming my projects w/ hyphens so the only solution I have now is to edit the structure post init.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is new feature from Gradle v5 : you can customize the target package name for generated sources with `--package` option, but by default it will be set with project name (which by default is the directory where project is generated) : see this commit  https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/785497c5a5f99566af0824f3000ac5a8c02c42d6#diff-4599bfb18cb3897a6a7c00bad52b11ba

Comment: from the source code: it does not seem possible anymore to set empty package name, unfortunately.